# No implicit conversion of String into Integer using JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently trying to display a certain field of JSON but getting this error when trying to do so.

Controller

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

class CatalogController < ApplicationController

    # GET /feeds
    # GET /feeds.json
    def index
      # GRAB THE URL
      url = 'https://api.import.io/store/connector/ab589079-436a-47da-923c-c77cb572491d/_query?input=webpage/url:http%3A%2F%2Flinxspiration.com%2F%23_%3D_&&_apikey=dc9014801ce443229a302ec1db31bc7683360af6669d43767164345452e9faef39e958817471e8c77f894d1032293acc8656cefa3df03123ee06a331f313c7f131ed345f4bf0fa8f460a80a6e9c4cbc1'
      response = HTTParty.get(url)

      # PARSE THE RESPONSE
      @elements = response.parsed_response["results"]
      @parsed = @elements["results"]["media_images"]

    end

end
```

View

```
<%= @parsed %>
```

Comment: on which line is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `response.parsed_response["results"]` is an array of hashes. So you don't have one 'media_images'. You have `media_images` for every element of the array. You can collect them into array like this:

`@parsed = @elements.collect { |e| e['media_images'] }`

Comment: How would I go about displaying each image within my view? e.g. <%= @parsed.each do %>?

Comment: Yes
<% @parsed.each do |img| %>
  <%= image_tag(img) %>
<% end %>

Answer (score 0):

The exception makes me think that you're trying to access an `Array` as a `Hash`. Because `Array`s take an index, Ruby is trying to turn the passed key into an `Array` index.

Try your code in the `rails console` and step through it carefully.